# How can I keep the default `yank-pop` behaviour after installing swiper?

Tags: ivy, yank, counsel, swiper

Swiper replaces the behaviour of the `M-y` command (`yank-pop`) with its own implementation, which shows the contents of the kill ring.

I like the default behaviour of `M-y` prior to installing this package (the Emacs default), and would like to go back to that. How could I achieve this while keeping swiper?

According to the [readme](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper#counsel), it replaces `yank-pop` with `counsel-yank-pop`, however this doesn't look like a simple remap, because calling `yank-pop` directly shows the ivy kill ring prompt.